# How to show total run time in seconds in Python templates using {{ curly brackets }}?

Tags: python

We use python and format the runtime (taken from django) like this:

`{{ job.crawl_time|date:"f" }}s`

Only this outputs microseconds

**Question**: How can we output the total time in seconds (total seconds!), preferably in the template?

Something like?

`{{ job.crawl_time|date:"s" }}s` Nope

`{{ job.crawl_time|date:"f" / 1000 }}s` Nope

`{{ job.crawl_time }}s` Nope

Comment: Have you tried looking at the official docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: Always. Always.